# mysql join 5 tables

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

Well guys, I have five tables here [sessions, users,users_2_groups,permissions_attribute and permissions]. For simplifying let's consider:

- sessions table has two columns: sid and userid
- users table has two columns : userid and user_type_id
- users_2_groups has two columns : userid and usergroupid
- permissions_attribute has two columns : perm_att_id and perm_att_label
- permissions table has five columns:permissionid,perm_att_id,perm_appendto,perm_appendid and permission_value

i have create a query to check if user have the right permission by his id[userid],group[usergroupid] and type[user_type_id] and it's work perfectly,but for one permission and i want to modify my query to support checking for one or more permissions.
here is my query that support one permissions:

```
SELECT p.permissionid,f.userid,f.user_type_id,t.perm_att_id,t.perm_att_label,p.permission_value 
FROM 
(SELECT s.userid AS userid,u.user_type_id FROM sessions s,users u WHERE s.sid='f7b24e6cc4f9325c946d7c4522411ab1' AND u.userid=s.userid) AS f 
JOIN permissions_attribute AS t ON t.perm_att_label='show-dashboard'
JOIN permissions AS p ON (p.perm_att_id=t.perm_att_id AND p.perm_appendto='user' AND p.perm_appendid=f.userid AND p.permission_value=1)
OR (p.perm_att_id=t.perm_att_id AND p.perm_appendto='type' AND p.perm_appendid=f.user_type_id AND p.permission_value=1)
OR (p.perm_att_id=t.perm_att_id AND p.perm_appendto='group' AND p.perm_appendid IN (SELECT usergroupid FROM users_2_groups  WHERE userid=f.userid ) AND p.permission_value=1)
```

**UPDATE:**
the permissions module work like this:

- select userid from sessions table by session id [sid]
- get the permissions that we need to check from permissions_attribute table where perm_att_label column hold the name of permissions [in my code its support only one,but i need to make it support more than one.
- we can assigned the permissions to user by three way:

  - by assigned permissions to the user directly [userid]
  - by assigned permissions to the group [usergroupid]
  - by assigned permissions to the user type [user_type_id]
    when i check for a permissions, query shall be search for them into all three way [user,group and type].
    now i need to pass tow or more permissions label [perm_att_label] to check if its assigned or not?

Have I been clear? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How does permissions_attribute relate

Comment: it holds the permission label where i used to check permissions,in my sql you will see one "show-dashboard" only and i need to pass more than one like "show-dashboard" and "show-profile".

Comment: Let's try that again: How does the `permissions_attribute` table relate to the other tables? beyond that, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 1):

The readability of your query is pretty low. A couple of things to keep in mind when writing sql queries:

1. Don't use implicit joins (like `sessions s,users u`). This syntax is generally frowned upon.
2. Avoid `SELECT (...) FROM (SELECT ... FROM)` constructs. These are terrible for readability. If you must select something from another query, use `WITH`. In this case however, I don't see any reason you need this.
3. When joining tables, usually only add the joining columns in the `ON` clause. Use the `WHERE` clause for more general constraints like `s.sid='f7b24e6cc4f9325c946d7c4522411ab1'`
4. Try to avoid unnecessary duplicate code as much as possible. In this query, you duplicate a lot of conditions, for example `p.permission_value=1`

With this in mind, I rewrote your query. However, the solution to your question seems rather trivial. Is there any reason why this wouldn't work?

```
SELECT p.permissionid, u.userid, u.user_type_id, t.perm_att_id, t.perm_att_label, p.permission_value
FROM sessions s
INNER JOIN users u ON u.userid=s.userid
INNER JOIN permissions_attribute t ON t.perm_att_label='show-dashboard'
INNER JOIN permissions AS p ON p.perm_att_id=t.perm_att_id
WHERE s.sid='f7b24e6cc4f9325c946d7c4522411ab1'
AND p.permission_value IN (1,2,3,...) -- <- have you tried this?
AND ((p.perm_appendid=u.userid AND p.perm_appendto IN ('user','type'))
  OR (p.perm_appendto='group' AND p.perm_appendid IN 
        (SELECT usergroupid FROM users_2_groups WHERE userid = u.userid);
```

Comment: it wouldn't work because i want to check for more than one permissions in same time,if you look to the field perm_att_label you will see it check for one permission named "show-dashboard",so i want to make this query be able to check more than one.